# Javascript: How does using a class benefit over creating objects at the time they are needed?

Tags: javascript

I am unsure of why I would exactly need to use a class here or perhaps a better way to say it is: I am not sure how a class is helpful as opposed to just forming objects on the fly.

```
 export default class Car {
        constructor(type="not specified", engine="V6") {
              this.type = type;
              this.engine = engine;
        }
        getType() {
              return `the car type is ${this.type}`
        }
    }
```

**main.js**

```
import Car from Car.js;



let allCars = [];

function userSubmittedCarInfo() {
   let typeValue = document.getQuerySelector('.input-type').value;
   let engineValue = document.getQuerySelector('.input-engine').value;

   



   // not sure the difference of just sending data as an object vs sending as class object?
   
   //option 1 .... for object on the fly that I can post to server.  Push it to list if I 
   // need a running list of all objects later on. 
  
    let obj = {
      type: typeValue,
      engineValue: engineValue,
   }
   allCars.push(obj);
   

   //option 2... second option is create an instance of Car class
   
   let obj = new Car(typeValue, engineValue)



   fetch('url-i-am-posting-to', {
      car: obj
   })
    
}
```

Comment: in JS, classes helps defining object shapes, but if you have a well written object-literal shape, there is no benefit whatsoever *except* with classes you define methods, or accessors, once per each *instance*, as opposite of *N* times per each object (see `getType` in this case).

Comment: https://medium.com/@vapurrmaid/should-you-use-classes-in-javascript-82f3b3df6195

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: What is `fetch()` supposed to do with a "car"?

Answer (score 2):

Classes are generally useful when you want to tie together *data* with *methods* that operate on that data. Your `Car` here gives instances both properties on the instance (data) as well as a method that operates on the data (`getType`).

If you actually do want to call the `getType` method at certain points in the code, or if you add additional methods on the Car, having a `class` is quite a reasonable choice - you just have to pass in the data, and it'll return an object containing both the data and useful methods for that data.

But if you *don't* need methods - like in this example, it doesn't look like you're ever calling `getType` - then a class may well not provide any benefit, and could be considered to only be adding confusing overhead, and using an object literal would make good sense instead (arguably, even more sense).

Comment: perfect explanation, that helped cleared it up in my head.  Thank you very much.